# How to include Google Search results on a webpage

Tags: html, google-search

I'm doing a webpage about apples (the fruit), I want to include Google search results for apple recipes on the bottom of the page. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using iframes, but you might want to consider some alternatives... you might want to create a [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/) to serve results only from recipe websites. And, instead of using a frame to display results, you might want to simply make the custom search engine available, so that, only if a user is interested in finding a recipe, he/she may do so. Something else to consider... you might want to monetize this, in which case using [Google AdSense](https://www.google.com/adsense/) would be the way to go.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/search?q=apple+recipe" />
```

If you want to use an iframe, you can use the code above; however, this is not a good design decision.

Comment: This is not possible anymore in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced inclusion of Google results check out this: https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/#fonje

You can use ajax based search queries for your keywords and put the results on your website.
There are examples in the docs

**Update:**
As the API is deprecated you can now alternatively just scrape the results from Google instead of using their API.
There is an open source PHP scraper that can be included into your website at http://scraping.compunect.com

Comment: Shame, not supported anymore 
`The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/`

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/?q=apples">See recipes about bananas</a>.
```

Comment: this is a link to the search results, not the search results.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question, is incomplete, and the associated comment does not conform to the SO code of conduct. Please improve your answer.